# Display Animated Loading Text while Running Another Operation

Tags: c#, loops, directory, loading

If I am making a call to `Directory.GetFiles()` that takes around 10 seconds to complete, how can I (at the same time) display animated loading text? I have a class to take care of the animation but am unsure if this is possible with a single function call (instead of a loop).

Comment: use BackgroudWorker http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var ct = tokenSource2.Token;

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Replase  with yor animation code

                int i = 0;
                while (true)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i++/10.0);
                    Task.Delay(100).Wait();

                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                }
                // end of replace
            }, tokenSource2.Token);

            Task.Delay(10000).Wait(); //replace with Directory.GetFiles() 

            tokenSource2.Cancel(); // replace with animation stop code

        }
    }
```

Comment: Within the task, how can I test whether the task has completed? When I try to use `task` within the block, an error is thrown that it is undeclared.

Comment: In my example task ends when parent `Task` cals `tokenSource2.Cancel()` and `ct.IsCancellationRequested` becomes `true`. Within task you control lifecycle by youself. Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693.aspx)